# in scipy.optimize.minimize - could not be broadcast together data with shapes (2,) (2,5)

Tags: python, scipy-optimize-minimize

I cannot cope with shapes mismatch in `scipy.optimize.minimize` here in this example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Create the matrices
X = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[2,1,0,3,4]])
y = np.array([[0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,0]])

# Display the matrices
print("matrix x:\n", X)
print("matrix y:\n", y)

# compute the distance matrix
dist_mat = distance_matrix(X, y, p=2)

# display distance matrix
print("Distance Matrix:\n", dist_mat)

loss_res = lambda z: 0.5 * z ** 2 * (np.abs(z) <= 1) + (np.abs(z) - 0.5) * (np.abs(z) > 1)
f_to_optMin = lambda w: np.sum(loss_res(X @ w.ravel() - y)) # (2,) 10, (2,5)

res= minimize(f_to_optMin, (10,10,10,10,10,))
print(res.x)
```

seems, that problem/solution is rather simple, but I don't see how to make it working. Can somebody help me, please?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\NEW docs\dist_mat.py", line 33, in <module>
    res= minimize(f_to_optMin, ([1,1,1,1,1,]))
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 618, in minimize
    return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 1201, in _minimize_bfgs
    sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 261, in _prepare_scalar_function
    sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._update_fun()
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 233, in _update_fun
    self._update_fun_impl()
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 137, in update_fun
    self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)
  File "C:\Users\adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py", line 134, in fun_wrapped
    return fun(np.copy(x), *args)
  File "E:\NEW docs\dist_mat.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    f_to_optMin = lambda w: np.sum(loss_res(X @ w.ravel() - y)) # 2, 10, [2,5]
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,5)
```

Comment: Please add the error with traceback.

Comment: added... error arises in Sum of Squared Errors func `f_to_optMin`

Comment: `X` is already the same shape as `y`, so what is your intention by `X @ w`? (Ignoring the `.ravel()` part, since `w` is 1-dimensional already.)

Comment: intention was to model multidimensional multivariate/multioutput/multilabel Classification  (I corrected - changed 2 to 0 in one place of y) - if it is possible, though sounds complicated (everywhere multi - but not this is the sence) & sample is small, but logics is needed in the code as an example of *Distance Metric Solutions*

Comment: well, to be more precise: not classification, but Clustering as of distance metric solution (minimized sum of squared errors )

Comment: I recognized the incorrectness of my solution - because Clustering is Unsupervised & cannot be projected to y here. As it, I suppose, ought to be Model-free, not Model-based solution. Is scipy.optimize.minimize inappropriate for finding min sum of Euclidean distances? probably, yes?.. and will the sollution be the center of any of binary class ? perhaps not... I'm stucked a little bit with the applicability of `minimized sum of Euclidean distances` in real tasks! what could be good  aim to use it for (in any usefull example) ? and if this problem could be stated as Covex optimization problem ?

Comment: and besides, if to use [K-means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641024/15893581). Though I previously thought like "K-means optimizes the (sum of within-cluster-) sum of squares aka variance aka sum of squared Euclidean distances."

Comment: .. [geometrical median to minimize Euclidean distances.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57277493/15893581) with scipy.optimize.minimize - is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with

```py
X @ w.ravel() - y
```

The left side of the subtraction has shape (2) while the right has shape (2,5). To reconcile that, according to the numpy broadcasting rules, you could replace y by its transpose, and have the subtraction applied by rows. I tested it:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Create the matrices
X = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[2,1,0,3,4]])
y = np.array([[0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,2]])

# Display the matrices
print("matrix x:\n", X)
print("matrix y:\n", y)

# compute the distance matrix
dist_mat = distance_matrix(X, y, p=2)

# display distance matrix
print("Distance Matrix:\n", dist_mat)

loss_res = lambda z: 0.5 * z ** 2 * (np.abs(z) <= 1) + (np.abs(z) - 0.5) * (np.abs(z) > 1)
f_to_optMin = lambda w: np.sum(loss_res(X @ w.ravel() - y.T)) # (2,) 10, (2,5)

res= minimize(f_to_optMin, (1,1,1,1,1,))
print(res.x) # [ 0.91638545  0.41921018 -0.07796579 -0.0237285  -0.2451989 ]
```

and it seems to work. Not knowing what you are trying to solve, it's impossible to know if this is what you want or need though.

Comment: oh, really - I wanted to solve for minimum of SSE of Euclidean_distances, but used X, y instead of distances - that's my fault. But for corrections with Transpose - Thanks!

Comment: does your answer means that we need to broadcast (2,) to (5,2) shapes instead of my faulty (2,) to (2,5) ?

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what it means

Comment: yes, and I probably was incorrect in Loss (Huber) & Metric used here, more suitable for *regression* problem, than my over-complicated attempt to try the *clustering* problem of minimizing spatial_distances Withing-Group & maximizing spatial_distances Between-Group

Comment: OFF: multi-class *classification* - possible [softmax loss_fx](https://gist.github.com/tsaith/290471a7ef508850139a) algo

Comment: OFF: [minimize(logistic_loss...)](https://github.com/UBC-MDS/DSCI_572_sup-learn-2/blob/master/lectures/lecture2_gradient-descent.ipynb)

Comment: P.S. [clustering-algorithms](https://neptune.ai/blog/clustering-algorithms)

Comment: BTW, minmax_kmeans can be found [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/96845/pulp.LpProblem)

Comment: [solution for Euclidean k-center problem](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-k-means-clustering-and-feature-selection-is-np-hard) with pulp... BTW, looks not very beautiful with iris_ds...